# Jenkins with mvn missing dir error

Tags: java, spring, maven, docker, jenkins

I've created jenkins job which need to build something very simple

Clone this repo

https://github.com/g0t4/jenkins2-course-spring-boot

cd to project

https://github.com/g0t4/jenkins2-course-spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-atmosphere

and run `mvn compile`

inside the atmosphere there is a `pom.xml` file, so what could be the reason to no finding it ?

I've configure the task like following

[image]

[image]

The error in the log is:

Checking out Revision 4bde91e33e2860b2aab142028c04eff37b7791f2 (refs/remotes/origin/master)

> git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
>   git checkout -f 4bde91e33e2860b2aab142028c04eff37b7791f2
>   Commit message: "Adding in jacoco code coverage"
>   First time build. Skipping changelog.
>   [atmo_local] $ **mvn -f spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-atmosphere/pom.xml complie**
>   FATAL: command execution failed
>   java.io.IOException: error=2, **No such file or directory**

**update**

When I click on my mac  `mvn -v` I get

```
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d2b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T18:41:47+02:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.9/libexec
Java version: 1.8.0_144, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.13.2", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

**update 2** this is the global configuration

[image]

[image]

Comment: try adding the -X flag to maven (verbose mode) (I can't see your screenshots from here, but the flag will help)

Comment: @spi - thanks, where I should add it ? , in the goals ?

Comment: in the place where you configure the maven command. maybe in the job, or globally in the settings

Comment: or maybe in the goals, that may work

Comment: @spi - Ok I've tried it and the job runs `mvn -f spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-atmosphere/pom.xml complie -X` and I got the same error: 
`FATAL: command execution failed
java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory,` , any idea?

Comment: you should have got a lot more informations that will help the diagnostic... or else the flag was ignored

Comment: ho! isnt there a typo here? _complie_ instead of _compile_?

Comment: @spi - Thanks i've changed it and same issue :(

Comment: @RaynD do you actually have maven installed and working with jenkins, other than this?

Comment: @eis  - I run it locally in my machine and i've maven , I was able to execute the mavn commands on the same project when I clone it via cli ...

Comment: @spi - Did you try to simulate it in your machine and it works ?

Comment: @RaynD but can you run maven with Jenkins? can you try without the file name component?

Comment: @eis - what does it mean without find name component ?

Comment: @eis - I've installed the latest jenkins with maven plugin . this is not sufficient  ?

Comment: @eis - btw I've try the same with docker and install Jenkins `https://hub.docker.com/_/jenkins/` and I run exactly the same , and I got the same error

Comment: @RaynD no, that's not sufficient. You have to configure maven (location) to jenkins. And by without file name component, I meant without having the "POM" specified (the arrow in your screenshot).

Comment: @eis - I remove the path and It runs  mvn compile and I got the same error ? How should I overcome it ? if you have and idea please write it as answer since this is the first time that I use jenkins

Comment: @RaynD no since I don't have Jenkins at work and I even can't see your screenshots (they are firewalled). But the procedure should be quite strait forward: 1) install java 2) install maven 3) register them in $PATH, so you can launch ```java -version``` and ```mvn -v``` without errors and 4) configure jenkins to run ```mvn clean install```

Comment: First clone example project into a single repository of your own...and use that from within Jenkins. Set the root pom `pom.xml` and no directories etc.

Comment: @khmarbaise - I was able to do it locally when creating new dir and clone the repo cd to the `atmosphere` repo and run mvn compile which works successfully . now i've install jenkins and configure it as above and I got the missing dir error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've installed the latest jenkins with maven plugin . this is not sufficient ?

No, it's not. You have to also configure Maven location to jenkins.

The steps are something like:

1. Click Manage Jenkins
2. Click Global Tool Configuration
3. In the JDK section click Add JDK button, uncheck Install automatically checkbox and enter Name and JAVA_HOME values to point to right locations
4. In the Maven section click Add Maven button, uncheck Install automatically checkbox and enter Name and MAVEN_HOME value (whatever it is in your jenkins system)
5. Click Apply and then Save